# Rebus - Bus with sql transport in MemoryCache callback

Tags: rebus

I have a message handler which accumulates the messages in a MemoryCache for a given time, so that only the last one will be handled.

When the callback happens i want to forward another message to an handler using sql transport, but the sql connection has now been closed.

The code looks something like this:

```cs
public IBus SqlBus { get; set; }

public async Task Handle(ServiceMessage message)
{
    await base.Handle(() =>
    {
        cache.Set(CacheKey, message, new CacheItemPolicy()
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(10),
            RemovedCallback = new CacheEntryRemovedCallback(CacheCallback),
        });

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }, message);
}

private void CacheCallback(CacheEntryRemovedArguments arguments)
{
    if (arguments.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired)
    {
        var message = arguments.CacheItem.Value as ServiceMessage;
        SqlBus.Send(new AnotherMessage()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

Is there any approaches which lets me do this?

Answer (score 0):

When is the `CacheCallback` method called, and on which thread?

It sounds to me like the problem is that the thread calling `CacheCallback` has a value in `AmbientTransactionContext.Current`, which is where Rebus enlists queue operations when it can.

If the transaction context is was somehow preserved even though the handler finished executing, then the associated cached items (like e.g. the `SqlConnection` and `SqlTransaction` associated with the SQL transport) will be closed.

Comment: The CacheCallback is called when the expiration runs out, or when another message is inserted into the System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache. It is called on a different thread.

Comment: A worker thread, i don't know the inner workings of the MemoryCache :S